examples of trigonometric functions $f(x)$ such that $\int_0^M e^{if(x)} dx$ becomes a desired value
Let $f(x)$ be a non-constant differentiable real-valued function defined on $x \in [0,M]$.
What are some examples of trigonometry functions $f(x)$ such that it satisfies the following equations:
\begin{align}
\int_0^M \cos(f(x)) dx = -0.5 M, \quad \int_0^M \sin(f(x)) dx = 0?
\end{align}
I started off with $f(x) = a\sin(kx)$. A real-valued version of the Jacobi-Anger expansion gives
\begin{equation}
\int_0^M \cos(f(x))dx = MJ_0(a) + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{J_{2n}(a)}{2nk}\sin(2nkM), \\
\int_0^M \sin(f(x))dx = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{J_{2n-1}(a)}{(2n-1)k}(1-\cos(2nkM)).
\end{equation} I first thought about setting $k = \pi/M$ so that second terms in both of the equations above vanish. However, since the minimum value of $J_0(a)$ is around $-0.4$, the first condition is impossible to achieve.
I want to see if one can come up with another analytical solutions on $f(x)$ (being a trig function) such that the condition holds. Any advice or help would be very much appreciated.

$f(x) = a\sin(kx)$ would never work because $f(0)$ can't be $0$ to satisfy your conditions

@NinadMunshi Right. I concluded that $f(x)$ being a single sine or cosine term would never work. The main obstacle I'm facing right now is that when it comes to 2 or more terms, it seems very difficult to develop the integrals.
